# Issue calculating month end date in 4GL

Tags: sql, informix, 4gl, genero

This routine is returning 12/31/2016 instead of 12/31/2015 and messing up a report.
Any idea where it is going wrong?

```
    LET date_month = MONTH(p_selection.date_from)
IF  date_month = 12 THEN 
    LET date_month = 1
    LET p_selection.date_from = p_selection.date_from + 1 UNITS YEAR
    LET date_thru = date_month,"/01/",YEAR(p_selection.date_from)
    LET p_selection.date_from = p_selection.date_from - 1 UNITS YEAR
ELSE 
    LET date_month = date_month + 1
    LET date_thru = date_month,"/01/",YEAR(p_selection.date_from)
END IF

LET p_selection.date_thru = date_thru CLIPPED

IF YEAR(p_selection.date_thru) <> YEAR(p_selection.date_from) THEN 
    LET p_selection.date_thru = p_selection.date_thru + 1 UNITS YEAR
END IF 
    LET p_selection.date_thru = p_selection.date_thru - 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. One thing I notice about your question is that it contains part of an IF statement in the second block — it is missing the second END IF. It isn't clear whether there's another assignment in it or whether the END IF simply got dropped (it probably did). The second problem is that it is not 100% clear what the input value for `p_selection.date_from` has when you get the erroneous result, nor whether the value stored in `p_selection.date_from` or `p_selection.date_thru` is wrong, or both are wrong. Make sure everything is spelled out.

Comment: It is often helpful to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.  Your material is close enough that it isn't a big problem, but please keep the ideas in those links in mind in future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input `p_selection.date_from` is 12/01/2015 ...

`IF date_month = 12` returns TRUE, so `date_thru` gets calculated as 01/01/2016

But then the second `IF` statement also returns TRUE, adding another year to `p_selection.date_thru` (01/01/2017), before decrementing it one day to 12/31/2016.

Seems to me that someone has had several goes at trying to calculate the date of the last day of the month, and one or the other method is required, not both. The one that appears first in your code is particularly dubious - there's an assumption that `DBDATE` is US format when it casts between DATE and CHAR, which is entirely unnecessary.

A far simpler solution would be to simply calculate:

```
LET p_selection.date_thru = 
    MDY(MONTH(p_selection.date_from), 1, YEAR(p_selection.date_from))
    + 1 UNITS MONTH - 1 UNITS DAY
```

In other words find the first day of the selected month, add a month and subtract a day. Simple and robust, it works at the year boundary and when a leap day occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some old code that's not seen the light of day in a while, but is still valid I4GL.

#### ltmonth.4gl

```
{
    @(#)$Id: ltmonth.4gl,v 1.4 1990/04/05 11:02:05 john Exp $
    @(#)Sphinx Informix Tools: General Library
    @(#)Find last day of this month
    @(#)Author: JL
}

FUNCTION last_of_this_month(edate)

    DEFINE
        edate   DATE        { Effective date (frequently TODAY) }

    IF edate IS NULL THEN
        RETURN edate
    END IF

    RETURN first_of_next_month(edate) - 1

END FUNCTION {last_of_this_month}
```

#### fnmonth.4gl

```
{
    @(#)$Id: fnmonth.4gl,v 1.4 1990/04/05 11:02:03 john Exp $
    @(#)Sphinx Informix Tools: General Library
    @(#)Find 1st of next month
    @(#)Author: JL
}

FUNCTION first_of_next_month(edate)

    DEFINE
        edate   DATE,       { Effective date (frequently TODAY) }
        mm      INTEGER,    { Month number }
        yy      INTEGER     { Year }

    IF edate IS NULL THEN
        RETURN edate
    END IF

    LET mm = MONTH(edate) + 1
    LET yy = YEAR(edate)
    IF mm > 12 THEN
        LET mm = 1
        LET yy = yy + 1
    END IF

    RETURN MDY(mm, 1, yy)

END FUNCTION {first_of_next_month}
```

#### lastthismonth.spl

And here's some SPL based on the I4GL above:

```
-- @(#)$Id: lastthismonth.spl,v 1.2 2008/07/20 02:54:37 jleffler Exp $
--
-- @(#)Create last_of_this_month Stored Procedure
--
-- @(#)Version: ltmonth.4gl,v 1.4 1990/04/05 11:02:05 john
-- @(#)Sphinx Informix Tools: General Library
-- @(#)Find last day of this month
-- @(#)Author: JL
--
-- Alternative expression: 
-- (MDY(MONTH(dateval), 1, YEAR(dateval)) + 1 UNITS MONTH) - 1 UNITS DAY

CREATE PROCEDURE last_of_this_month(edate DATE DEFAULT TODAY)
    RETURNING DATE AS last_of_this_month;

    IF edate IS NULL THEN
        RETURN edate;
    END IF

    RETURN first_of_next_month(edate) - 1;

END PROCEDURE {last_of_this_month};
```

#### firstnextmonth.spl

```
-- @(#)$Id: firstnextmonth.spl,v 1.1 2008/07/20 02:21:13 jleffler Exp $
--
-- @(#)Create first_of_next_month Stored Procedure
--
-- @(#)Version: fnmonth.4gl,v 1.4 1990/04/05 11:02:03 john
-- @(#)Sphinx Informix Tools: General Library
-- @(#)Find 1st of next month
-- @(#)Author: JL

CREATE PROCEDURE first_of_next_month(edate DATE DEFAULT TODAY)
    RETURNING INTEGER AS first_of_next_month;

    DEFINE mm   INTEGER;    { Month number }
    DEFINE yy   INTEGER;    { Year }

    IF edate IS NULL THEN
        RETURN edate;
    END IF

    LET mm = MONTH(edate) + 1;
    LET yy = YEAR(edate);
    IF mm > 12 THEN
        LET mm = 1;
        LET yy = yy + 1;
    END IF

    RETURN MDY(mm, 1, yy);

END PROCEDURE {first_of_next_month};
```

Note the alternative expression.  It works, but it is an incredible mixture of DATE and DATETIME calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
FUNCTION last_of_month(m,y)
DEFINE m,y SMALLINT
    RETURN MDY(m,days_in_month(m,y),y)
END FUNCTION
```

with an appropriate function days_in_month() to return 28,29,30,31 as appropriate based on month and year

For the OP you should be creating a function and re-using it, rather than potentially repeating logic like it looks like you are doing.

What I really wanted to comment on, was that at Genero we were discussing wether to add built-in functions to do these types of calculations.  If everyone has their own first_of_month, last_of_month, add_months then the thought was we should include them in the language rather than having everyone reinvent the wheel.  As part of the discussions, what I learned was that the + 1 UNITS MONTH, as used by RET in his answer is as he says leap-year safe.  For some reason I thought it wasn't and had tended to avoid it, and write in the style of JLefflers answer.  Looking at other 4GL/Genero customers library code I have seen, I suspect other developers thought the same thing.

Comment: Hi @fourjs.reuben, `+1 UNITS MONTH` is problematic when adding to a date on the 29/30/31st, but you can rely on every month having a 1st. :-)

Comment: @RET True, but what I was trying to say is that `+1 UNITS MONTH` will return a valid date for the 29/30/31st cases.  Perception I've got from looking at various customers code is that developers have avoided that syntax unnecessarily.

Comment: I think @JonathanLeffler can probably verify this, but I think that fix for month arithmetic in date columns is only fairly recent. It is definitely the case that `MDY(1,31,2015) + 1 UNITS MONTH` would error on older versions.

Comment: Turns out Jonathan already has, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33142330/14750 . The fix was introduced in 11.70.FC5

Comment: + n UNITS MONTH works appropiately, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11497714/366797